# How to set a device min width and scale lower ones

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I received a design with the lowest width of 767px. The design is somewhat "crowded" width texts and this texts are adjusted to the background very well.

I wanted you to ask what is the best approach to make this 767px design as the smallest available. Lower widths should not receive a vertical scrollbar, but should scale to the min-width on the initial load on that devices.

I tried to solve this with adjusting the meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, min-width=767px, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

But it doesn't seem to work, like I want to. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post a fiddle and explain a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a more detailed search, and found what I needed here https://www.brendanlong.com/setting-a-minimum-viewport-width-for-responsive-pages.html:

```
var MIN_WIDTH = 767;
var viewport = document.createElement("meta");
viewport.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
if (screen.width < MIN_WIDTH) {
    viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=" + MIN_WIDTH);
} else {
    viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
}
document.head.appendChild(viewport);
```

This does exaclty what I need, if the screen width is less than 767px the viewport meta tag is adjusted with content="width=767"
Devices with a lower screen width now using 767px as screen width and scaling down the page on initial load to a 100% and the correct zoom level

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This code should be inside the `<head>` part of your `html` document.
now use this code and replace your_class_name with your class name.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    .your_class_name {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.